# Migrating Calligraphy to version 3 does not have a get() method for the font path

Tags: android, calligraphy

The original library of [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) had a `get()` method to get the font path. Example:

```
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;

CalligraphyConfig.get().getFontPath();
```

I was using that to set it to my Input's, example:

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), CalligraphyConfig.get().getFontPath());
passwordInput.setTypeface(face, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Now, with [Calligraphy 3](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy) there is not a CalligraphyConfig's class.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'CalligraphyConfig'

*I have followed the instructions for [Installation](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy#installation).*

I cannot find a way to get the font path using the new version of Calligraphy. What is the new way to get it?

My goal is to get the font path using the new [Calligraphy 3](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy).